# Convert special HTML character codes like &quot; to normal characters

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, json, razor

I have some code in my .cshtml file that outputs a JSON string:

```
window.TEAgent = {
    Id: @User.AgentId ,
    Roles: '@User.Roles'
}
```

But this is how it looks when I view page source or call `window.TEAgent` with JavaScript:

```
window.TEAgent = {
    Id: 47650 ,
    Roles: '{&quot;RolesForUser&quot;:[&quot;Agent&quot;,&quot;WVS&quot;]}'
}
```

How can I convert each `&quot;` back to `"` so that it looks like this?

```
{"RolesForUser":["Agent", "WVS"]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740.aspx) to prevent the string from being HTML encoded:

```
window.TEAgent = {
    Id: @User.AgentId,
    Roles: @Html.Raw(User.Roles)
}
```